# Content missing in html file scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape the content of this site: http://www.whoscored.com/Matches/824609/Live . If i view the html-file in Chrome under the network tab am i able to see everything i want to scrape. But if i run the script below is a lot of data is missing in the results, data in JSON format. Its data of every specific event during the game. Why is the result different when i inspect the content in chrome and when i scrape the site?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/Matches/824609/Live'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
print soup
```

Comment: change the parser `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"lxml")`,  if you are trying to parse parts of the page loaded by javascript you might be out of luck